# How the normalization condition implies the following relation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, unitarity, quantum-states, normalization

Using equation 2.35 from Peskin and Schroeder:

$$
|\vec{p}\rangle=\sqrt{2 E_{\vec{p}}} a^{\dagger}_\vec{p} |0\rangle
$$

should lead to

$$
U(\Lambda)|\vec{p}\rangle = |\Lambda \vec{p}\rangle,
$$
where a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ was implemented as some unitary operator $U(\Lambda)$.

Two questions:

1. How do I deduce the second equation?
2. What is exactly happening in here? We are applying a boost $\Lambda$ to the particle with momentum $\vec{p}$, which is a unitary operator (that is, satisfies the relation $U U^{\dagger} = U^{\dagger} U$?

PS: I am well aware of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82439) question, but I wouldn't like to work it backwards (at least, I was not able to understand like that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2)**

Say that a Lorentz boost on $|p\rangle$ is given by an operator $A$. If $|p\rangle$ was normalised to begin with, you would want your theory to maintain its normalisation regardless of it being boosted to $|Ap\rangle$.

So if $\langle p| p\rangle = 1$, then you would also want $\langle A p| Ap\rangle =1$, but $\langle A p| Ap\rangle = \langle p A^\dagger|Ap\rangle = \langle p|A^\dagger A|p\rangle $. Requiring this to be $ = 1 = \langle p| p\rangle $ means that $A^\dagger A=1$, that is that $A$ is unitary.

So let's call it $U(\Lambda)$.

**1)**

In 2.35 you have defined the normalisation condition
$$ |\mathbf{p}\rangle = \sqrt{2 E_\mathbf{p}}a^\dagger_\mathbf{p}|0\rangle.$$

If you now boost this state to a momentum $\mathbf{q}$, you would want this state to also be normalised like:

$$ |\mathbf{q}\rangle = \sqrt{2 E_\mathbf{q}}a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}|0\rangle.$$

From what learnt in the previous question,
$$|\mathbf{q}\rangle  = U(\Lambda)|\mathbf{p}\rangle.$$

So instead of $\mathbf{q}$, let's call it $\Lambda\mathbf{p}$. Why invent a new name and waste a new variable.

Hence:
$$ |\Lambda\mathbf{p}\rangle = U(\Lambda)|\mathbf{p}\rangle.$$